# Python 2.7 Socket programming ports

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had an exercise of port carousel which means that I need to build a server-client which the server asks the client for a port and then they starting to listen to the port that given, and this is the loop I got a error and I don't know how to fix it.

server:

```
import socket
import random

def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1729))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    (client_socket, server_socket) = server_socket.accept()

    done = False
    while not done:
        port = client_socket.recv(4096)
        client_socket.send('i got the port' + port)
        port = int(port)

        if port != 1:
            server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
            continue
        else:
            done = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
import socket
import random


def main():
    print 'hi at anytime enter 1 to break the loop'
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1729))
    done = False

    while not done:
        port = client_socket.send(raw_input("enter port:"))
        data = client_socket.recv(4096)
        print data
        port = int(port)
        if port != 1:
            client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
            continue
        else:
            done = True
    client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the error output for the server:

> File "C:/Cyber/ServerFolder/ports_carrousel.py", line 18, in main
>           server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
>       AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'bind'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main function, you do the following:

```
(client_socket, server_socket) = server_socket.accept()
```

but, server_socket.accept() actually returns two objects. The first, is a socket object, and the second one is a tuple that contains (sourceIPString, sourcePort).

Thus, by using this line of code, outlined above, you are essentially overriding the server_socket by a tuple object.
Notice that later, in line 18, you are trying to access the "bind" function of a socket, but, using a reference to a tuple object, that does not implement such a function.

What you should be doing is something along the lines of

```
(client_socket, client_connection_info) = server_socket.accept()
```

and adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things wrong here. First, `accept` returns a 2-tuple containing the newly-connected socket, and the client's address (which is itself a 2-tuple of IP address and port number). It does *not* return two sockets. But you're overwriting your `server_socket` variable with the second returned value. That doesn't make sense and it's why the interpreter is telling you that the 2-tuple has no `bind` attribute: it's not a socket object. The `accept` call should look something like this:

```
client_socket, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
```

Next, after receiving the new port number from the client, you must create a *new* socket (you cannot re-use the same listening socket), then `bind` that new socket to the new port, then `listen`; finally you can `accept` a new client connection from the new listening socket.

You should also `close` sockets you're finished with so that you don't continually leak file descriptors. That means each time you receive a new port number from the client, you should close the client socket, *and* the listening socket, then create a new listening socket (and `bind` and `listen`), then accept the new client socket.

Altogether that will mean restructuring your code in the server significantly. You need to pull the creation of a listening socket down into your main `while not done` loop.

Another thing to keep in mind. On the client side, immediately after sending the port number to the server, you're attempting a `connect` to that new port number. However, it's almost certain that your `connect` request will reach the server before the server has had a chance to create a new listening socket, and bind it. So your client will either need to delay a moment before attempting to connect, or it will need to have logic to retry the `connect` for some period of time.

EDIT:
Also, you must create a *new* socket on the client side too when reconnecting. Once a stream socket has been bound to a port (which also happens automatically when you `connect`), you can never use it to `bind` or `connect` to a different address/port.